# Homogenous Coordinate Ring of Symmetric Product of Projective Space

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, projective-space

I am trying to compute the homogenous coordinate ring of Sym$^2$**P**$^2$. I know that this is equal to
$k[$**P**$^2 \times$**P**$^2]^{S_2}$ where $S_2$ acts on $k[$**P**$^2 \times$**P**$^2]$ by simultaneously switching $x$ and $x'$, $y$ and $y'$, and $z$ and $z'$ in the homogenous coordinates $[x:y:z;x':y':z']$. Then I believe that:
$k[$**P**$^2 \times$**P**$^2]^{S_2} \simeq k[xx',yy',zz',xy'+yx',xz'+zx',yz'+zy']/($relations between these generators$)$

Is this correct? Or should I first embed **P**$^2 \times$**P**$^2$ into a higher dimension projective space and then do something similar.

**Edit:**
I've also tried first embedding **P**$^2\times$**P**$^2$ into **P**$^8$ with the Segre embedding and have that then
$k[$**P**$^2 \times$**P**$^2] \simeq k[xx',xy',xz',yx',yy',yz',zx',zy',zz']/(xy'-yx',xz'-zx',yz'-zy').$
However, I am then unsure how to find the elements of this ring fixed by the $S_2$ action. Clearly $xx', yy', zz', xy'+yx',xz'+zx',yz'+zy'$ are all fixed in $k[xx',xy',xz',yx',yy',yz',zx',zy',zz']$ but I am confused about how the quotient affects this.

Comment: @Eoin I wasn't sure if $x+x'$, $y+y'$ and $z+z'$ would be valid since they're not bihomogenous, so they wouldn't be invariant under scaling $[x:y:z]$ by something different from what you scale $[x':y':z']$. If those are included then would it be correct? With the addition of those it would also generate all of the non-bihomogenous multisymmetric functions of higher degree I believe.